# Subscribe to new JointState messages

Tags: joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm new in ROS and have a problem making the joint_state_publisher publish JointState messages on a topic different from /joint_states.
I wanted to publish arbitrary joint states from the terminal window and therefore I intended to use the source list parameter in my launch file as proposed here in the joint_state_publisher Package Summary.

But I cannot make it work by adding the parameter to my .launch file. I tried something like

\param name="source_list" value="joint_states_test" type="str"/>

What do I have to do in order to make it work?

Thanks,

Mike

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60975/subscribe-to-new-jointstate-messages/) by [Mike_321](https://answers.ros.org/users/4704/mike_321/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-17

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [E1000ii](https://answers.ros.org/users/4878/e1000ii/) on 2013-09-20**:
I have the same problem. But i think quest must be edited to change the beggining of the question in order to make clear. what is intended is to use the imput option for joint_state_publiser to take messages from an arbitrari topic and republish them in /joint_states. Title is not veri descriptive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now is an old thread. But i answer anyway for the next noob like that could end up here.

To pass list parameters to a nodes you should use the tag '**rosparam**' instead of
'param'. You could see how to use it [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam).

On my launch file the joint_state_publisher looks like that:

```
<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
    <rosparam param="source_list">["my_controller/robot/joint_states"]</rosparam>
</node>
```

It worked and I'm now visualizing on rviz my real robol state. Note that you could put whatever you want instead of my_controller/robot/joint_states.

---

Originally posted by [E1000ii](https://answers.ros.org/users/4878/e1000ii/) with karma: 178 on 2013-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2016-12-19**:
And if you want to test this, try something like:

```
rostopic pub my_controller/robot/joint_states sensor_msgs/JointState '{header: {seq: 0, stamp: {secs: 0, nsecs: 0}, frame_id: ""}, name: ["the_urdf_joint_name"], position: [1.0], velocity: [0.0], effort: [0.0]}' --once
```

**Comment by [marawy_alsakaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/31902/marawy_alsakaf/) on 2017-11-13**:
from where you get joint state for a real robot?